# Coldfusion Reading XML HTTP without extension

Tags: java, xml, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I was thinking I'll call like webservice but it not working.

Task: Read XML Content from webserver port:80756. when I hit this url (http://192.168.22.80:80756) in browser output.

```
<NTMonitorDoc>
<SMTPAddr>0.0.0.0</SMTPAddr>
<LineErrors>0</LineErrors>
<LogErrorsCount>0</LogErrorsCount>
<PopupErrorsCount>0</PopupErrorsCount>
<IsDTSProcRunning>1</IsDTSProcRunning>
<IsDTSMailProcRunning>0</IsDTSMailProcRunning>
<IsInboundProcRunning>0</IsInboundProcRunning>
<CTFTOErrorCount>0</CTFTOErrorCount>
</NTMonitorDoc>
```

Coldfusion Code:

```
<cfhttp url="http://192.168.22.80:80756" result="r">
<cfdump var="#r#" label="myResult">
```

[image: Coldfusion OUTPUT]

Comment: Rather than trying to use the default document. Try to hit the specific document. Something like `http://192.168.22.80:80756/index.cfm`. Also are you using Adobe ColdFusion or Lucee?

Comment: this is the problem it is the hardware xml status report i don't what is the extension it is output coming anyway it seems like im very near to solution i'll post here when it done .... thank you very much... being very supportive

Comment: Can you even reach the target server from ColdFusion? This might be a firewall issue

Comment: it was a permission issue from lucee it. but still i don't know, what was the issue and how to solve it. when i transfer my code on cf9 it is working great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a permission issue from lucee it.

Comment: Thanks that you answer on SO, consider to improve your answer some (what did you do exactly to solve it)